# Cyclic Navigation makes destination unknown to NavController

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

I have a use case where the user answers a quiz with question/answers in `fooFragment` below. When the user clicks "next" and there's another question/answers left, I want to navigate back to a `fooFragment` to render the new question/answers.

This works fine. Now, let's say I hit the back button and navigate back to the fragment to the left of `fooFragment`, let's call it `Frag1`. If I'm now to press the same button that earlier got me to `fooFragment`, I get a `navigation destination ... is unknown to this NavController` error.

Granted, `android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx` is still in alpha (I'm running `1.0.0-alpha11`) so bugs are more or less frequent. But has anyone a workaround for this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by setting the pop destination explicitly (to `Frag1`).